# The dropdown change does not affect other users Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, user-input

Private sheet changes only affect current users, in this case, is the dropdown.

I have a google sheet with editable dropdown ( B1, B2, F2, and G2 ) that determine the result of my query. But, I have no idea how to make the dropdown changes only affect the current user and not all users who are opening it. Is there a way to do it keep with dropdown? It's okay if the only way is completely different from my initial way. Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19UTGRcA5csV2sFzD7htB8HG_ROeLRG9q1kNW1C97AEs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Or i just make new sheet for each value in user in dropdown, and make hyperlink list on the master sheet?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create a filtered view:

[image: 0]

the next best thing you can do is create a sheet for every user